# Problem retrieving region in US with geograpy3

Tags: python, geolocation, geograpy

Using geograpy3 (https://pypi.org/project/geograpy3/):

```
> import geograpy
> text = "Welcome to beautiful Seattle"
> p = geograpy.get_geoPlace_context(text=text)
> p.cities
['Seattle']
> p.countries
['United States']
> p.regions
[]
```

Is there a package or dataset I need to download?

Answer (score 0):

I am answering as a committer of geograpy3. There is a new locator interface intended for improvements in disambiguation and location. It is not fully integrated yet with the Natural Language Processing part yet - issues and pull requests are welcome ...

```py
def testStackOverflow64418919(self):
        '''
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64418919/problem-retrieving-region-in-us-with-geograpy3
        '''
        examples=['Seattle']
        for example in examples:
            city=geograpy.locateCity(example,debug=False)
            print(city)
```

Result:

```
Seattle (US-WA(Washington) - US(United States))
```